# How to catch parallel session? (Ruby on Rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have read that parallel session is when at the same time a user can be logged in into the web application multiple times. I have Ruby on Rails application and I don't know how to catch the parallel session in the app so I can show to the user some warning and log him out.

Comment: What do you need to prevent simultaneous logins?

Comment: I don't know. That is why I am asking

Comment: It's generally not a problem.